# How do you search for and delete a phrase from a string in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a python new-comer, so there is probably a simple answer to this question, but I have looked and found nothing.

I want to define a function that when this is entered: "function(abcdefg123, fg1, " ")" the return is this: "abcde 23". I think it would look like this:

```
def function(something, what_to_deleat, what_to_substitute):
  if str(what_to_deleat) in str(something):
    return ## Code that replaces "what_to_deleat" with "what_to_substitute"  within "something"
  else:
    return something
```

A practical application (and the one I'm wanting to use this for) would convert 25.0 into 25 if 'function("25.0", ".0", "")' was entered.

Comment: string.replace() method would do. Here https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest solution would be

```
 def function(something, what_to_delete, what_to_substitute):
    return something.replace(what_to_delete, what_to_substitute)
```

Of course you would not need to write your own function here at all...

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Comment: Thanks... so why doesn't this work?

Comment: def cut(n):
  if str(n) == str(n).replace(".0", ""):
    return str(n).replace(".0", "")
  else:
    return str(n)

Comment: I tried a bunch of things, but it either gives an error or doesn't do anything. e.g. cut(25.0) just gives 25.0, not 25 like I want.